# cannot import name SharePointSite

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got the same error message both on my desktop and on my Windows 2008 R2 server -

Here's the code -

```
from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener

server_url = "http://sharepoint/"
site_url = server_url + "path/to/page/Forms/AllItems.aspx"

opener = basic_auth_opener(server_url, "acct", "password")

site = SharePointSite(site_url, opener)

for sp_list in site.lists:
    print sp_list.id, sp_list.meta['Title']
```

When running it I get the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\sharepoint.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener
  File "C:\temp\sharepoint.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener
ImportError: cannot import name SharePointSite
```

What's going on?  The package is in the location -

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sharepoint
```

I can import other packages just fine.  for example, lxml works fine.

```
from lxml import etree
```

no problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You named your script `sharepoint.py` and that masks the library:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\sharepoint.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener
  File "C:\temp\sharepoint.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener
ImportError: cannot import name SharePointSite
```

Look at the filenames in the traceback, you can see that the script ends up importing *itself*; when Python starts your script it loads it as `__main__`, so importing `sharepoint` loads your own file one more time, at which point it fails to import itself again.

Rename your script to something else.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaand I feel like an idiot ;)  Thanks this solved it.  Marking solved in t-minus 10 minutes.